# nginx не проксирует на apache в docker-е

Tags: linux, apache, nginx, docker

**Есть docker-compose**

```
version: '2'
services:
    nginx:
        image: nginx:latest
        ports:
            - 80:80
            - 443:443
        volumes:
            - ./hosts:/etc/nginx/conf.d
            - ./www:/var/www
            - ./logs:/var/log/nginx
        links:
            - php
            - portainer
            - apache
            - kibana
    apache:
        image: httpd:2.4
        ports:
            - 8080:8080
        volumes:
          - ./www:/var/www
          - ./httpd:/etc/apache2
        links:
          - php
    php:
        build: ./images/php
        links:
            - mysql
        volumes:
            - ./www:/var/www
    mysql:
        image: mysql:8
        command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
        restart: always
        ports:
            - 3306:3306
        volumes:
            - ./mysql:/usr/local/mysql
        environment:
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: secret
    portainer:
        image: portainer/portainer
        container_name: portainer
        command: --no-analytics
        ports:
            - 9000:9000
        volumes:
            - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
    mailcatcher:
        image: yappabe/mailcatcher
        ports:
            - 1025:1025
            - 1080:1080
    kibana:
        image: docker.elastic.co/kibana/kibana:6.6.1
        ports:
            - 5601:5601
```

в папке ./hosts лежат *.conf
Часть из них - проксируют на portainer, mailcatcher и т.д. - работают.

Пример того что на apache

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  sinica.local;

    location ~ \.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|css|zip|tgz|gz|rar|bz2|doc|xls|exe|pdf|ppt|txt|tar|mid|midi|wav|bmp|rtf|js)$ {
        root /var/www/sinica.local/frontend/web;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny  all;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_pass $scheme://apache:8080;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
        proxy_connect_timeout 120;
        proxy_send_timeout 120;
        proxy_read_timeout 180;
    }
}
```

При открытии, например http://sinica.local/favicon.ico - nginx отдает иконку. все ок.

Но при входе в http://sinica.local/ - **502 Bad Gateway**

в ./httpd

httpd.conf - пробовал разные варианты, даже левое содержимое писал. Ошибку не получал - вывод, apache не видит этот конфиг. внутри контейнера этот файл лежит в **/etc/apache2**

```
NameVirtualHost *:8080
IncludeOptional sites-enabled/*.conf

Listen 8080
```

И, соответственно там-же лежит папка  **sites-available**

**sinica.local.conf**

```
<VirtualHost *:8080>

    ServerName sinica.local
    ServerAlias www.sinica.local

    ServerAdmin tony@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/sinica.local/frontend/web

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

Гугл перерыл в ответах, решение не нашёл.

error.log

```
6#6: *1 no resolver defined to resolve apache, client: 10.0.2.2, server: sinica.local, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "sinica.local"
```

**UPD**
httpd.conf

```
ServerRoot "/usr/local/apache2"

Listen 8080

LoadModule mpm_event_module modules/mod_mpm_event.so
#LoadModule mpm_prefork_module modules/mod_mpm_prefork.so
#LoadModule mpm_worker_module modules/mod_mpm_worker.so
LoadModule authn_file_module modules/mod_authn_file.so
#LoadModule authn_dbm_module modules/mod_authn_dbm.so
#LoadModule authn_anon_module modules/mod_authn_anon.so
#LoadModule authn_dbd_module modules/mod_authn_dbd.so
#LoadModule authn_socache_module modules/mod_authn_socache.so
LoadModule authn_core_module modules/mod_authn_core.so
LoadModule authz_host_module modules/mod_authz_host.so
LoadModule authz_groupfile_module modules/mod_authz_groupfile.so
LoadModule authz_user_module modules/mod_authz_user.so
#LoadModule authz_dbm_module modules/mod_authz_dbm.so
#LoadModule authz_owner_module modules/mod_authz_owner.so
#LoadModule authz_dbd_module modules/mod_authz_dbd.so
LoadModule authz_core_module modules/mod_authz_core.so
#LoadModule authnz_ldap_module modules/mod_authnz_ldap.so
#LoadModule authnz_fcgi_module modules/mod_authnz_fcgi.so
LoadModule access_compat_module modules/mod_access_compat.so
LoadModule auth_basic_module modules/mod_auth_basic.so
#LoadModule auth_form_module modules/mod_auth_form.so
#LoadModule auth_digest_module modules/mod_auth_digest.so
#LoadModule allowmethods_module modules/mod_allowmethods.so
#LoadModule isapi_module modules/mod_isapi.so
#LoadModule file_cache_module modules/mod_file_cache.so
#LoadModule cache_module modules/mod_cache.so
#LoadModule cache_disk_module modules/mod_cache_disk.so
#LoadModule cache_socache_module modules/mod_cache_socache.so
#LoadModule socache_shmcb_module modules/mod_socache_shmcb.so
#LoadModule socache_dbm_module modules/mod_socache_dbm.so
#LoadModule socache_memcache_module modules/mod_socache_memcache.so
#LoadModule watchdog_module modules/mod_watchdog.so
#LoadModule macro_module modules/mod_macro.so
#LoadModule dbd_module modules/mod_dbd.so
#LoadModule bucketeer_module modules/mod_bucketeer.so
#LoadModule dumpio_module modules/mod_dumpio.so
#LoadModule echo_module modules/mod_echo.so
#LoadModule example_hooks_module modules/mod_example_hooks.so
#LoadModule case_filter_module modules/mod_case_filter.so
#LoadModule case_filter_in_module modules/mod_case_filter_in.so
#LoadModule example_ipc_module modules/mod_example_ipc.so
#LoadModule buffer_module modules/mod_buffer.so
#LoadModule data_module modules/mod_data.so
#LoadModule ratelimit_module modules/mod_ratelimit.so
LoadModule reqtimeout_module modules/mod_reqtimeout.so
#LoadModule ext_filter_module modules/mod_ext_filter.so
#LoadModule request_module modules/mod_request.so
#LoadModule include_module modules/mod_include.so
LoadModule filter_module modules/mod_filter.so
#LoadModule reflector_module modules/mod_reflector.so
#LoadModule substitute_module modules/mod_substitute.so
#LoadModule sed_module modules/mod_sed.so
#LoadModule charset_lite_module modules/mod_charset_lite.so
#LoadModule deflate_module modules/mod_deflate.so
#LoadModule xml2enc_module modules/mod_xml2enc.so
#LoadModule proxy_html_module modules/mod_proxy_html.so
LoadModule mime_module modules/mod_mime.so
#LoadModule ldap_module modules/mod_ldap.so
LoadModule log_config_module modules/mod_log_config.so
#LoadModule log_debug_module modules/mod_log_debug.so
#LoadModule log_forensic_module modules/mod_log_forensic.so
#LoadModule logio_module modules/mod_logio.so
#LoadModule lua_module modules/mod_lua.so
LoadModule env_module modules/mod_env.so
#LoadModule mime_magic_module modules/mod_mime_magic.so
#LoadModule cern_meta_module modules/mod_cern_meta.so
#LoadModule expires_module modules/mod_expires.so
LoadModule headers_module modules/mod_headers.so
#LoadModule ident_module modules/mod_ident.so
#LoadModule usertrack_module modules/mod_usertrack.so
#LoadModule unique_id_module modules/mod_unique_id.so
LoadModule setenvif_module modules/mod_setenvif.so
LoadModule version_module modules/mod_version.so
#LoadModule remoteip_module modules/mod_remoteip.so
#LoadModule proxy_module modules/mod_proxy.so
#LoadModule proxy_connect_module modules/mod_proxy_connect.so
#LoadModule proxy_ftp_module modules/mod_proxy_ftp.so
#LoadModule proxy_http_module modules/mod_proxy_http.so
#LoadModule proxy_fcgi_module modules/mod_proxy_fcgi.so
#LoadModule proxy_scgi_module modules/mod_proxy_scgi.so
#LoadModule proxy_uwsgi_module modules/mod_proxy_uwsgi.so
#LoadModule proxy_fdpass_module modules/mod_proxy_fdpass.so
#LoadModule proxy_wstunnel_module modules/mod_proxy_wstunnel.so
#LoadModule proxy_ajp_module modules/mod_proxy_ajp.so
#LoadModule proxy_balancer_module modules/mod_proxy_balancer.so
#LoadModule proxy_express_module modules/mod_proxy_express.so
#LoadModule proxy_hcheck_module modules/mod_proxy_hcheck.so
#LoadModule session_module modules/mod_session.so
#LoadModule session_cookie_module modules/mod_session_cookie.so
#LoadModule session_crypto_module modules/mod_session_crypto.so
#LoadModule session_dbd_module modules/mod_session_dbd.so
#LoadModule slotmem_shm_module modules/mod_slotmem_shm.so
#LoadModule slotmem_plain_module modules/mod_slotmem_plain.so
#LoadModule ssl_module modules/mod_ssl.so
#LoadModule optional_hook_export_module modules/mod_optional_hook_export.so
#LoadModule optional_hook_import_module modules/mod_optional_hook_import.so
#LoadModule optional_fn_import_module modules/mod_optional_fn_import.so
#LoadModule optional_fn_export_module modules/mod_optional_fn_export.so
#LoadModule dialup_module modules/mod_dialup.so
#LoadModule http2_module modules/mod_http2.so
#LoadModule proxy_http2_module modules/mod_proxy_http2.so
#LoadModule lbmethod_byrequests_module modules/mod_lbmethod_byrequests.so
#LoadModule lbmethod_bytraffic_module modules/mod_lbmethod_bytraffic.so
#LoadModule lbmethod_bybusyness_module modules/mod_lbmethod_bybusyness.so
#LoadModule lbmethod_heartbeat_module modules/mod_lbmethod_heartbeat.so
LoadModule unixd_module modules/mod_unixd.so
#LoadModule heartbeat_module modules/mod_heartbeat.so
#LoadModule heartmonitor_module modules/mod_heartmonitor.so
#LoadModule dav_module modules/mod_dav.so
LoadModule status_module modules/mod_status.so
LoadModule autoindex_module modules/mod_autoindex.so
#LoadModule asis_module modules/mod_asis.so
#LoadModule info_module modules/mod_info.so
#LoadModule suexec_module modules/mod_suexec.so
<IfModule !mpm_prefork_module>
    #LoadModule cgid_module modules/mod_cgid.so
</IfModule>
<IfModule mpm_prefork_module>
    #LoadModule cgi_module modules/mod_cgi.so
</IfModule>
#LoadModule dav_fs_module modules/mod_dav_fs.so
#LoadModule dav_lock_module modules/mod_dav_lock.so
#LoadModule vhost_alias_module modules/mod_vhost_alias.so
#LoadModule negotiation_module modules/mod_negotiation.so
LoadModule dir_module modules/mod_dir.so
#LoadModule imagemap_module modules/mod_imagemap.so
#LoadModule actions_module modules/mod_actions.so
#LoadModule speling_module modules/mod_speling.so
#LoadModule userdir_module modules/mod_userdir.so
LoadModule alias_module modules/mod_alias.so
#LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so

<IfModule unixd_module>
User daemon
Group daemon

</IfModule>


<IfModule dir_module>
    DirectoryIndex index.html
</IfModule>

<Files ".ht*">
    Require all denied
</Files>

ErrorLog /proc/self/fd/2

LogLevel warn

<IfModule log_config_module>
    LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
    LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b" common

    <IfModule logio_module>
      LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\" %I %O" combinedio
    </IfModule>

    #
    CustomLog /proc/self/fd/1 common

</IfModule>

<IfModule alias_module>
    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ "/usr/local/apache2/cgi-bin/"

</IfModule>

<IfModule cgid_module>
</IfModule>

<Directory "/usr/local/apache2/cgi-bin">
    AllowOverride None
    Options None
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<IfModule headers_module>

    RequestHeader unset Proxy early
</IfModule>

<IfModule mime_module>

    TypesConfig conf/mime.types

    AddType application/x-compress .Z
    AddType application/x-gzip .gz .tgz

</IfModule>

<IfModule proxy_html_module>
Include conf/extra/proxy-html.conf
</IfModule>

<IfModule ssl_module>
SSLRandomSeed startup builtin
SSLRandomSeed connect builtin
</IfModule>

IncludeOptional sites-enabled/*.conf
```

**nginx.conf**

```
user  nginx;
worker_processes  1;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    resolver 127.0.0.11 ipv6=off;
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    keepalive_timeout  65;

    #gzip  on;

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
}
```

Comment: У nginx должен быть где-то error.log, читайте его (но как в докере читать, я не в курсе)

Comment: @andreymal добавил

Comment: `resolver 127.0.0.11 ipv6=off;` в nginx.conf секция http что дает? [enSO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35744650/docker-network-nginx-resolver)

Comment: @TotalPusher посмотрю

Comment: @TotalPusher 2019/03/12 08:55:41 [emerg] 1#1: "http" directive is not allowed here in /etc/nginx/conf.d/sinica-local.conf:1

Comment: Вы не туда добавили. Нужно добавить внутрь http наравне с другими строками. Конфиг в студию, если не почините!

Comment: у меня нету http просто в конфиге. @TotalPusher 
в папке ./hosts лежат *.conf - я в нужном мне конфиге и делаю.

Я обернул указанный выше конфиг в http{} и внутри добавил resolver.

Comment: эти конфиги инклудятся в более общий конфиг. попробуйте без обертки http

Comment: расшарил с докера /etc/nginx(до этого была /etc/nginx/conf.d)

Comment: @TotalPusher `2019/03/12 17:57:04 [error] 6#6: *19 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 10.0.2.2, server: sinica.local, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://172.20.0.7:8080/", host: "sinica.local"`

Comment: Как видно, апстрим подставляется верный, на апач

Comment: На сколько я понимаю - дальше дело за апачем, он уже обрывает запрос. Верно?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/90956/discussion-between-sinica-and-total-pusher).

Comment: После решения - выложу проект на github.

Answer (score 1):

Во-первых, nginx считает, что «apache» в директиве `proxy_pass` — это имя какого-то хоста, который он не может разрезольвить. Укажите вместо него 127.0.0.1 или явно пропишите `upstream`.

Во-вторых, мне кажется, лучше там же прописать не `$scheme`, а `http`.

Comment: Александр, apache будет нормально резолвиться, это Докер. А вот при резолве хост 127.0.0.1 внутри контейнера - сам этот контейнер, и рядом нет "соседей". А надо обращаться к соседнему контейнеру, который внутри докера, с IP типа 172.17.0.2.

Comment: http пробовал вместо $scheme

Comment: Александр, имя контейнера apache - это нормально для proxy_pass. С другими контейнерами(портайнер, маилкетчер, кибана) - работает

Comment: Ну, OK. Должен - значит, должен. Но, тем не менее, жалуется он именно на невозможность разрезолвить это имя.